# Linux NFS with direct IO

Tags: linux, nfs

Is there any way to use direct IO for NFS on Linux similar to AIX -dio option?

I cannot use O_DIRECT flag in open() system call.

Comment: When mounting, what about forcedirectio option?

Comment: It was not possible in that instance, but thanks for the suggestion anyway. Looks like it is the only option.